# document.getElementById onclick to also trigger function 2 / form 2

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Can anyone please advise where i am coding this wrong..

Once a user submits my form which has the Id of 'fwrdform' via the onclick, i need to trigger an additional function of my 'logout-form' so that the user is then also logged out of the site..

```
<script>
document.getElementById('fwrdform').onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();
};
</script>
```

It just doesn't seem to work and i cant get my head around why..

Thanks guys!

full coding that i am using is:

```
<a align="right" class="nav-link" href="http://EXAMPLE.COM/logout"
onclick="event.preventDefault();
document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
<font color="#FFFFFF" style="font-size: 14px !important;">Logout</font>
</a>

<form id="logout-form" action="http://EXAMPLE.COM/logout" method="POST" style="display: none;">
</form>


 ////////////////////////////////////////////////


<form id="fwrdform" class="d-flex justify-content-left" method="post" action="http://EXAMPLE.COM/addtocart">

<input type="hidden" value="1" name="quantity" aria-label="Search" class="form-control" style="width: 65px">

<input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="{{$product->id}}">
<input type="hidden" width="100" height="40" value="submit" src="submit.png" alt="Submit">


<a href="http://EXAMPLE.COM/checkout" target="_blank" value="submit"><img border="0" src="http//EXAMPLE.COM/submit.png" width="100" height="auto">
</a>
```

The aim is on a 'fwrdform' form submit, it sends the variables to an invoice on a new page which is a different url and also triggers the 'logout-form' of the current page that was the parent.

Comment: Can you post your HTML?

Comment: thank you just posted this above for you.. any help would be amazing!

Comment: Basically you want to do two different things on a single click, which I don't think a good idea and works properly

Comment: yes thats the aim.. that's very true.. i know it isnt the best way forward darn it. How about on form submit redirect parent page to another url.. cant seem to get that to work either..

Answer (score 1):

The only way I see that it's possible to do that is:

1. Go to the server-side code that `fwrdform` posts to.
2. At the bottom of the file, add a line of code that redirects the page to wherever the `logout` form is.

Here's a PHP example:

```
echo "<script> window.location.href = 'logout.php'; </script>";
```

And here's a NodeJS way:

```
document.write("<script> window.location.href = 'logout.php'; </script>");
```

Then add another line of code inside the `logout` form, same as those above, except it redirects back to the HTML page (`index.html`?).

Hopefully this helps you!